# How to get the "last seen..." data of a user

Tags: python-3.x, telethon

Within each Telegram application's GUI there's a setting for each user called "Last seen & online" if this setting is set to "Everybody" on an account other users should be able to view the `"Last seen..."` data of the account with the changed settings. I am building an application using Telethon and need this data for the current user. In the Telethon library how is it programmatically possible to get the `"last seen..."` data of a user other than the current user (the account making the Telethon API calls)?

[Example last seen online image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2SdV.png)

[Example "Last seen & online" settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxaVn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this;

```py
suser = await client.get_entity('username')
_last = None


from datetime import date
from telethon.tl.types import UserStatusOnline, UserStatusOffline

if isinstance(suser.status, UserStatusOnline):
    _last = date(suser.status.expires.year, suser.status.expires.month, suser.status.expires.day)

if isinstance(suser.status, UserStatusOffline):
    _last = date(suser.status.was_online.year, suser.status.was_online.month, suser.status.was_online.day)


print(_last)
```